# Transit scheduling using flow networks

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

I am studying the maximum/minimum flow question, and was given the following problem:

> A traveling agency has $n$ destinations on their service map, and it intends to maintain them with minimum amount of vehicles. Say a transit $i$ starts at ${s_{i}}$ and ends at $e_i$, and then for that transit, it needs another $ret_{ij}$ to return back to $j$ from destination $i$.

How can this transit schedule problem solved by using flow networks?